# setTimeout not executing

Tags: javascript

My setTimeout function does not want to work. I am not getting any of the alerts, so I'm assuming I did something incredibly stupid.

```
var timeout = 1000;
for(k=0;k<pages.length;k++)
{
    randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*pages[k].length);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: pages[k][randomnumber],
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if(data.indexOf('VIDEO_LENGTH') > 0)
                {
                    timeouttext = data.substr(data.indexOf('VIDEO_LENGTH')+12);
                    timeouttext = timeouttext.substr(timeouttext.indexOf('.'));
                    timeout = parseInt(timeouttext);
                    alert(timeout);
                }
                else
                    timeout = 1000;
                $('#loader').hide('fast','fade');
                $('#information').html(data);
                $('#information').show('fast','fade');
            }
        })
    },timeout);
    alert("PAGE " + k + " RandomNumber " + randomnumber + " : " + pages[k][randomnumber]);
    if(k==3) {
        k = 0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist me.

Comment: When you post questions, and you reference things like "data."  Its always useful to post what data looks like...

Comment: data is a simple text/html file that get's loaded with the ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: ok follow error:

the var k when you call the page url is not as expected. So try:

```
{
    randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*pages[k].length);
    var selectedIndex = k; // store current k
    setTimeout(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: pages[selectedIndex][randomnumber], // use stored k
 ...
```

Comment: if shorthand doesn't need parens.

Comment: yes... but if he close it, I suppose that he want open it :) however there is an odd number of parentheses

Comment: true, my fault. Edit your answer plz, so i can revote.

Comment: No matter how I coun't it, the number of parentheses match...

Comment: @DarkRanger According to the code you posted: the last `}` matches the big `for`-loop and the second-last `}`has no match. (Probably should be the match for the `if(k==3)`-construct.) What is the `console.log(status)` saying?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now. Sorry! As for the console, doesn't say anything. It just keeps hanging

Comment: @DarkRanger add this parenthesis for delete this blocking error and see all logs and alert

Comment: @DarkRanger please read my edit. Are there other errors?

Answer (score 1):

When you debug your code using FireBug or CHrome's developer tools do you see your Ajax requests?

It looks to me like your never getting to the "success" event for each request. Since you have no "error" event in your Ajax request you'd never see any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your setTimeout is correct. To further check for errors:

1. check in console whether your request is being sent.
2. add `error: function(){}` or `complete:function(){}` block which logs the status of the request, to see, if your server-side breaks your code.

edit: (i suggest you don't use the shorthand `if`, it's very error-prone.

Comment: I added an error block after LastCoder's answer. I get no response from that.

AFAIK, the request is being sent (according to console)

Comment: correct your if-condition missing `{` (check if the console promts any errors), and add an `console.log()` according to [ajax-Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the complete- or error-block to see, which status is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**Updated**) [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jG9Gn/7/).

```
var funfacts= ['URL1','URL2','URL3'];
var multimedia= ['URL4','URL5'];
var employees = ['URL6','URL7','URL8','URL9','URL10'];
var information = ['URL11','URL12','URL13'];

var pages = [funfacts, multimedia, employees, information];
var timeout=1000;
var t=0;
for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++)
{
    (function(value){
        for(j=0;j<pages[value].length;j++)
        {
            t++;
            (function(iv, ij){
                var tmo = timeout*t;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    callAjax(iv, ij);
                }, tmo);

            })(value, j); 
        }

    })(i);             
}

function callAjax(i, j)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: pages[i][j],
        success: function(data) {    
            if(data.indexOf('VIDEO_LENGTH') > 0) // indexOf should be checked if(var.indexOf('sometext')!=-1)
            {
                // your code
            }
            else
            {
                // your code
            }
        }
    });
}
```

​If everything else is fine then it should work.

you can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986588/calling-settimeout-function-within-a-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687679/jquery-ajax-inside-a-loop-problem) on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yours is the one that works best so far. But I still have an issue where there is no pause between the ajax calls. My console shows this: `GET http://localhost/info_screens/content/funfacts/0.html
GET http://localhost/info_screens/content/multimedia/0.html
GET http://localhost/info_screens/content/employees/0.html
GET http://localhost/info_screens/content/information/0.html` BUT there is no pause between any of those.

Comment: Just a comment on the `if(data.indexOf...` note: I know for a fact that `'VIDEO_LENGTH'` will never be on position 0. Although I know this, it's still not good coding practice, so I changed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Oops I've made a mistake, the "k" should be "i", url: pages[k][randomnumber] should be url: pages[i][randomnumber]

Comment: I picked up the last error. :) Async false does nothing. Still loads all the pages simultaneously and displays the last one...

Comment: Another thing I noted, it doesn't reset k to 0 either.

Comment: try this, at last of settimrout },timeout*i)})(i);

Comment: woooohoooo!! That did it. BUT, k is still not resetting to 0, so it's not fetching a new page from any of the pages arrays... Do you think I need to reset i to 0 too?

Comment: Can you do this test, if(k==3) { k=0;console.log(k);}

Comment: ok, k return as 0 after the fourth iteration which is correct. From what I can tell in the code, i needs to be 0, but I'm sure that's going to cause the freezing issue again.

Comment: hmmm... so now I'm back to square one... How do I restart the for-loop?

Comment: Basically, each `pages` array contains an array of URLs. These URLs are devided into 4 categories. The number of URLs are unknown. So, I grab a random URL from a category, and display that URL on screen. When the timeout event fires, it fetches the next category's random URL. I don't know if I'm clear enough...

Comment: Can you post how your pages array looks like ?

Comment: `Array ( funfacts => Array ('URL1','URL2','URL3') , multimedia => Array ('URL4','URL5') , employees => Array ('URL6','URL7','URL8','URL9','URL10') , information => Array ('URL11','URL12','URL13') )` - I tried to make it easy to understand. One thing to note is that it won't just have 4 or 5 URLs, it'll have a lot!

Comment: This is not a javascript array !

Comment: In javascript there is no associative array but array of objects.

Comment: I only sent that to make it easier to understand. funfacts, multimedia, employees and information are all arrays. And I use an array to put all those arrays in. So `pages` is defined as `var pages = new Array(funfacts, multimedia, employees, information);` and each of those arrays have string URLs in them.

Comment: Can you try this http://jsfiddle.net/jG9Gn/4/

Comment: It throws all 4 values at the same time.