# Meteor: observe a collection with reactiveVar

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, mongodb-query, dom-events

I have an application in which a user can manage multiple alarms (set a new alarm, edit it, or snooze)

When the alarm time is reached I need to notify the user. If a user clicks snooze, the time_end field gets 5 minutes added to it.

How can I track when the alarm times have been reached?

I have tried using a `collection.observe()` - but it only works once, on server start

**Server: Meteor Startup**

```
var expiredAlarms = Alarms.find({$and: [{"time_end": {$lt: moment()._d}}, {notification_sent: false}]});

expiredAlarms.observe({
    added: function(doc) {
        console.log('alarm timeout has been reached');
        processAlarmEnd(); //set notification_sent to true
    },
    removed: function(doc) {
        console.log('A notification has been sent');
    }
});
```

The above code only works when the app is started and processes all notifications for expired alarms - but once new alarms expire, nothing happens. My guess is because `moment()._d` does not change and the same old query is called over and over again.

Should I place this code in a `Tracker.autorun` - will that help? Any suggestions on doing this better/smarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make code execute in the future, you need to use `setTimeout`. In your `observe` query, don't care about the time, and in the `added` callback, calculate how many milliseconds remains till the alarm should go off, and use `setTimeout` to call `processAlarmEnd` after that amount of milliseconds.

You may also need to cancel a `setTimeout` with `clearTimeout` in the `removed` callback.

Comment: Yes that's a great idea...but how do I manage a large collection of setTimeout functions?

Comment: I guess this would work 
[How do you handle multiple instances of setTimeout()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315078/how-do-you-handle-multiple-instances-of-settimeout)

Comment: @Habib, yea, storing all the handles calls to `setTimeout` returns in an object in a variable outside the `added` and `removed` callbacks seems like a good idea. But make sure you delete the handles from the object when the alarms are over (so the object don' contains old handles that won't be used any more).