# setTimeout javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, settimeout

i was wondering how can I wait two times 5 seconds and do different things in each wait with phantomjs. Here's the code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://www.google.com/", function(status){

    var currentdate = new Date(); 

    console.log("\n\n" + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds() + "\n\n");


    setTimeout(function(){
        var currentdate1 = new Date(); 
        console.log("\n\n" + currentdate1.getHours() + ":" + currentdate1.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate1.getSeconds() + "\n\n");
        return "hahaha";
    }, 5000);


    setTimeout(function(){
        var currentdate2 = new Date(); 
        console.log("\n\n" + currentdate2.getHours() + ":" + currentdate2.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate2.getSeconds() + "\n\n");
        phantom.exit();
        return "hahaha";
    }, 5000);

});
```

Why is phantomjs the second setTimeout function is not working properly?? How can I solve this problem?
The output i want to achieve is this:

```
16:13:10
16:13:15
16:13:20
```

And not this (as now it does):

```
16:13:10
16:13:15
16:13:15
```

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: Both the timeouts starts **now**, and waits five seconds. You either nest one within the other, or you set the second one to 10 second.

Comment: See this for reset first timer before start second timer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/315133/6908226

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205489/wait-x-amount-of-seconds-in-phantomjs) and create a new account?

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, when you start one, the code doesn't stop running, it goes on with the other pieces, where you start the second `setTimeout`. To solve your issue, you need to either change the second timeout's delay to `10000` or you need to start the second timeout inside the first one.